Patenting a mathematical approximation code
If I have written a code to approximate something very efficiently, for example, some lines of code that efficiently calculates X^74 in a particular programming language (and leverages that particular language's features optimally), can I just make those lines of code an independent patent claim, with some brief explanations? What is the best way to approach this? Should the full 30 lines of code be included? There are many non-trivial pieces in the derivation.

You don’t patent code, you copyright code. You also can’t patent a mathematical algorithm. What you might be able to do is patent the use of an algorithm on a specific and tangible application. The likelihood of obtaining such a patent without the use of a patent attorney experienced in software patents is very, very low.

First of all, I would suggest starting clearly establishing the utility of your calculation. If your method calculates sin(x) that will be easy to justify but x^74 may not be as easy unless 74 is a particularily commonly occurring exponent in some field of practical applicability.
Next, one does not patent code itself, one patents the algorithm that the code implements. My opinion is that the simplest way to claim an algorithm is to use means-plus-function language and produce a flowchart of the algorithm accompanied by prose description, but there are other possible techniques. (One pitfall of the means-plus-function approach is that one must avoid a so-called "single means claim".)
It should usually be possible to claim independently of the specific programming language used. Naturally, your method likely depends on certain primitives being available and this dependency should be described but it is clear that it will work in other (possibly future) programming languages if they happen to provide the same primitives.
Others might say a mathematical calculation is an unpatentable abstract idea, but I think there would usually be considered to be an inventive concept where you have, as you claim, a novel method of calculation and the method as claimed is appropriately limited to being computer-implemented (rather than mental process).

A case last year declared a garage door opener as abstract Due to how it was claimed. There is no way a method of mathematical calculation wouldn’t be abstract.

@GeorgeWhite All computer-implemented methods reduce to calculations (the CPU of any computer performs only a stream of elementary calculations), so I would say that clearly some computer-implemented calculations are not abstract ideas. Historically (i.e., pre-Alice) the prohibition on mathematical algorithms have applied chiefly to cases where it was attempted to directly claim the formula for the result (more akin to a law of nature) rather than a procedure for calculating it more efficiently than trivially applying the formula (which is more akin to an engineering result).

I agree that a better floating point unit in a CPU, for example, would fit an exception to the abstraction doctrine - although SCOTUS has, so far, seen no need to define “abstract”.
